# How we should deal with people who offend islam and Muhammed(saw)?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad, punishment

Most people believe that they're allowed to say anything and they're allowed to express their opinions saying that it's 2015.
My question is that nowadays people make jokes about religions especially prophets, even offensive ones, so what I should do about them and how exactly should my reaction be?

Comment: You may be interested in Brother Nouman Ali Khan's thoughts on the Paris shootings (long, but an excellent video): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SzP8e9b_OT8&index=18&list=PLRrI7F8H5SviQXNrZVm__IT_L3zn2UGwT

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they are allowed to say whatever they want until their death. After that, in the Judgement Day, Allah will give their punishment for their sins. You are basically not authorized to attack them. But, you should defend your religion, without exceeding the limit. What is the limit? It is what they do.

If they attack with their tongue, you should defend with your tongue, with arguments and proofs.

If they attack with pen, you should defend with pen, with verses, hadiths and academical writings.

If they are mocking with religion, that means they are trying to get support of third people, they are playing to the tribune; you should play to the tribune too and get their support. Most of the people don't like unrespectful people and you should get their support. If anyone doesn't laughes, then nobody makes a joke.

If they are attacking physically, first you should call help from authorities like police. If they don't do their job, you should go to the upper authority like courts, or media, or international community. If any authority doesn't do its job, this is the point you can take initiative and defend yourself.

Comment: + They attack by their movies, you should defend by movies.

Comment: @kalahari What are your references? I've nowhere seen this: tongue for tongue, pen for pen etc. This is more of a philosophy maybe.

Comment: @zed111, You can search about the lives of prophets. How their enemies treated them and how they replied. Especially we have detailed knowledge of the life of Mohammad(puh). They said to him liar, wizard, poet etc, did he break their noses, or what? Also if there is an order, you should seek for your rights & safety in that order, otherwise there will be anarchy and zulm everywhere. But if the system/order doesn't give you your rights, then you should adjust the system so that it will keep your rights.

Answer (score 0):

I think that we Muslim who choose to live in non-Muslim countries are bound to respect the laws of the country where we live. In our civilised European countries we have abolished capital punishment. I think that Muslims are the last people who would want to reintroduce it. And certainly not for telling jokes.

Comment: This answer was to the original version of this "contribution", which advocated killing people for telling jokes. I am glad someone has removed these remarks.