# Cartoons That Offend Muslims

Tags: punishment

Why do Muslims get all up-in-arms (no pun intended) when someone draws a cartoon that spoofs your religion?

Are Muslims obliged to react to such actions? If so then how should they react?

Comment: They shouldn't, real example of Prophet Mohammed was that he wasn't a reactionary.  Many Muslims are just sensitive and need a chill pill.  Not to mention many 'scholars' are idiots who issued crazy veridcts.

Comment: Asking for a *why* would make it an opinion based question. And see also "[How we should deal with people who offend islam and Muhammed(saw)?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/23172/9123)".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should insults to the Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) be handled?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/how-should-insults-to-the-prophet-muhammad-pbuh-be-handled)

Comment: So, Mohammed does not have a sense of humor?

Comment: 1. * *..did not ...* 2. **See [this](http://www.hadithcollection.com/sahihbukhari/111-Sahih%20Bukhari%20Book%2078.%20Oaths%20and%20Vows/7710-sahih-bukhari-volume-008-book-078-hadith-number-627.html).** 3. There were occasions where he laughed and had fun with children(AFAIK) and his wives.

Answer (score 1):

As Muslims we continuously refer to the book of God to seek guidance in relation to worldly matters, and we also refer to the teachings of the prophet and find out how he reacted in similar situations

One similar situation was when the prophet has returned to his home town along with the minority who followed and also fled their home town because of the hardships they faced as a result of following prophet, he did not imprison them or kill them:

> "I speak to you in the same words as (Prophet) Yusuf(Joseph) spoke to
>   his brothers.  This day there is no reproof against you; Go your way,
>   for you are free".[2]

God and his prophet have continuously instructed us to be patient and have also assured us that we will be rewarded for aware patience

> and We will surely test you with something of fear and hunger and a
>   loss of wealth and lives and fruits, but give good tidings to the
>   patient,Those are the ones upon whom are blessings from their Lord and
>   mercy. And it is those who are the [rightly] guided. (2:157)

we are supposed to be patient even if this harm is being inflicted by those who surround us as shown below:

> Ibn Umar reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said,
>   “The believer who mixes with the people and endures their harm has a
>   greater reward than one who does not mix the people nor endures their
>   harm.”

Actions such as insulting our religion do tend to offend a lot of Muslims, and are viewed by us as evil actions, according to the hadeeth below we should always react to what is evil:

> Abu Saeed al-Khudri said: I heard the Messenger of Allah say: "Whoever
>   of you sees an evil action, let him change it with his hand; and if he
>   is not able to do so, then with his tongue; and if he is not able to
>   do so, then with his heart…" (Muslim)

But one may say "how should we react in such situation", well the verse below explains this:

> Not equal are the good deed and the bad deed. Repel evil by that which
>   is better, and then the one who is hostile to you will become as a
>   devoted friend. But none is granted it except those who are patient
>   and none is granted it except one having a great fortune. Surah
>   Fussilat 41:34-35
>
> “Call people to the way of your Lord with wisdom and good teaching,
>   and argue with them in the most courteous way” [16:125]

which concludes that the reactions of others such as Charlie Hebdo are definitely the wrong actions to take, as burning offices does not realy solve the issue to begin with.

There are other alternatives to approach such issue:
For example when someone in Denmark produced some cartoons, then some Muslim

- countries boycotted that country and forced it to take action.
- A lawsuit could have been funded by the Muslims against those who
  commited offences.
- The Muslims could have simply ignored such foolish acts.

We also believe in the day of judgement when every one will be judged for their actions by God himself, if we are not able to resolve such issue of others offending us in a civilised way then remembering this should ease our difficulties knowing that God is just and he will punish those who have inflicted harm upon others

> “On that Day, people will come forward in separate groups to be shown
>   their deeds: whoever has done an atom’s weight of good will see it,
>   but whoever has done an atom’s weight of evil will see that” (99:6-8).

There are many sites and blogs on the internet which provide details on how muslims should handle such abuse.

- http://muslimmatters.org/2012/09/16/39567/
- http://www.faithstreet.com/onfaith/2015/01/08/how-the-prophet-muhammad-dealt-with-insults/35723

God knows best

Comment: This answer is open to any improvements and corrections, please submit your edits!

Comment: You talk of God, but how has God shown himself to you?   Really, when you pray, you might as well be talking to the wall?   And if you were caught doing so, you would be taken away in a van likely as not.   Yet, you talk to this entity as though he were real.  I find it odd.  And , I could say the same to Christians, lest you take offense.

Comment: @TimSpriggs what you state in the comment is another topic, why don't you post your concerns in a question and hopefully I can try and answer it, perhaps the question may be "How do Muslims confirm the existence of God?"